# Zend Framework: get POST parameters

Tags: php, zend-framework

We're using Zend Framework 1.12 and in several actions we have:

```
$postParams = $this->getAllParams();
...
$domainModel->update($postParams)
```

I was wondering if it's a good approach of handling params. Or is it better to define what parameters we want to get like:

```
$postParams = array(
    'email' => $this->_getParam('email'),
    'company' => $this->_getParam('company')
)
```

Or maybe use array intersection function to filter out unexpected parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Best practice should be using

```
$postParams = array(
    'email' => $this->_getParam('email'),
    'company' => $this->_getParam('company')
);
```

Using array intersection may work (for checking the keys not values of course!)

Why is passing all params to $domainModel->update not so good?

Depends on logic of update but assuming that parameters are getting into database query, by manipulating http request i can inject some additional code or params into db query - maybe update the field you do not want to update by that particular action.

Downside of this approach is that when you change your model, you have to check your code for these params.

Answer (score 0):

If all columns in table (including IDs) can be changed, you can use getAllParams. Except one problem: POST can contain variables that are not table columns, so you will get an error on update (column '...' not found).

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good idea to pass all post parameters to model directly. Sometimes you may not want pass specific values to model.

Second, you may want to set some default values to the data in case its not provided in that case you can do `$this->_getParam('company', DEFAULT_VALUE)`

But i would say that usage of any method depends on your requirements and then you need to pick one which is most suitable for you.